# Re Create Cross Domain Issue in Local

Tags: ajax, spring, http, https, cross-domain

we developed an application in java with springs in back end and j query in front end for a client and is working fine in our local, but when moved to customer side testing environment they are facing a security risk warning in Internet explorer. it says that "this page contains information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?"
but in our local environment we never faced such issue.
the application has lot of AJAX calls going on each and every page to load data, and not in all pages the error is coming.. only in some pages the error is coming for the customer.
we need to re create the issue in our local in order to analyze the root cause and fix.
can anyone here help me how to re create the cross domain problem in local.

Comment: Are you sure it is a crossdomain issue? It could happen that the client testing environment run with HTTPS but the ajax petitions are pointing to HTTP

Comment: @jddsantaella yeah you are correct. client side testing environment runs with HTTPS, so do we need to change all AJAX Calls with HTTP to HTTPS? we are very near to our deadlines and is there any other way to fix it? i mean server side configuration without changing the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes when your web is under hpps (https url) but the browser is calling http for load part of the content (ajax, images, etc.). All references in your page should be to https for avoid the alert in IE. I am afraid there is no other way. Relatives urls will avoid you change from http to https from one environment to another.